# Null value when click commandButton

Tags: jsf

Here, XHTML code, Which have 2primeface datatable.
I want to pass dialog box inputText value to addRow() of Managed Bean with #{invoice.id} value.
But value of all inputText is become NULL.
After new row data will update in invoiceTable and display new entery.

```
<p:panelGrid columns="3">
                <p:outputLabel value="Enter Invoice Number :" />
                <p:inputText id="inputInvoiceNumber"
                    value="#{invoiceBean.invoiceNumber}" />
                <p:commandButton value="Search" type="submit">
                    <f:ajax execute="inputInvoiceNumber" render="outputInvoiceNumber" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <br />
            <p:dataTable id="outputInvoiceNumber"
                value="#{invoiceBean.invoices}" var="invoice">
                <p:column headerText="Invoice Id ">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.id}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Email">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.email}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Invoice Number ">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.invoiceNumber}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Date">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.date}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Delivery Note ">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.deliveryNote}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Supplier Reference">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.supplierReference}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Other Reference">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.otherReference}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Buyer Name">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.buyerName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Buyer Address">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.buyerAddress}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Dispatch Document Date">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.dispatchDocumentDate}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Dispatch Through">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.dispatchThrough}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Destination">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.destination}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Terms Of Delivery">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.termsOfdelivery}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Net Total">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.netTotal}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <br />
            <p:dataTable id="invoiceTable" var="invoiceProductsServicesDetail"
                value="#{invoiceBean.invoiceProductsServicesDetails}" border="1"
                editable="true">

                <p:column headerText="Sr. No.">
                    <p:outputLabel
                        value="#{invoiceProductsServicesDetail.serialNumber}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Description of Goods">
                    <p:outputLabel
                        value="#{invoiceProductsServicesDetail.descriptionOfGoodsOrService}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="HSN Code">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoiceProductsServicesDetail.hsnCode}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Quantity">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoiceProductsServicesDetail.quantity}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Rate">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoiceProductsServicesDetail.rate}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Percentage Discount">
                    <p:outputLabel
                        value="#{invoiceProductsServicesDetail.percentDiscount}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Amount">
                    <p:outputLabel
                        value="#{(invoiceProductsServicesDetail.rate) * (invoiceProductsServicesDetail.percentDiscount) }" />
                </p:column>


                <p:summaryRow>
                    <p:column colspan="5" style="text-align:right">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Total" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{invoiceBean.netTotal}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:summaryRow>

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton value="Add Invoice" type="button"
                        onclick="PF('addInvoice').show();" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>


            <p:dialog id="invoiceDialog" header="Add Invoice"
                widgetVar="addInvoice" minHeight="40" showEffect="explode"
                hideEffect="fold">
                <table border="1" id="dialogTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td><p:outputLabel value="Description Of Goods Or Services" /></td>
                        <td><p:outputLabel value="HSN Code" /></td>
                        <td><p:outputLabel value="Quantity" /></td>
                        <td><p:outputLabel value="Rate" /></td>
                        <td><p:outputLabel value="Percentage Discount" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p:inputTextarea id="description"
                                value="#{invoiceBean.descriptionOfGoodsOrService}" cols="45"
                                required="true" label="Description"
                                requiredMessage="Description Require Entry" /></td>

                        <td><p:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.hsnCode}" size="6" /></td>

                        <td><p:inputText id="quaintity"
                                value="#{invoiceBean.quantity}" size="3" styleClass="Alingment"
                                required="true" label="Quantity"
                                requiredMessage="Quantity Require Entry" autocomplete="off" /></td>

                        <td><p:inputText id="rate" value="#{invoiceBean.rate}"
                                styleClass="Alingment" required="true" label="Rate"
                                requiredMessage="Rate Require Entry" autocomplete="off" /></td>

                        <td><p:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.percentDiscount}"
                                size="2" styleClass="Alingment" autocomplete="off" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Save New Invoice"
                    action="#{invoiceBean.addRow}" update=":form:invoiceTable growl"
                    process="@this invoiceTable" onsuccess="PF('addInvoice').hide();"
                    onerror="PF('addInvoice').show();">
                    <f:ajax render=":form:invoiceTable" />
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
            </p:dialog>
            <br />
            <p:commandButton value="Create Pdf"
                action="#{createPdf.createPdfFile}" ajax="false">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{invoiceBean.invoiceNumber}"
                    target="#{createPdf.invoiceNumber}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

Here, Managed Bean addRow() method which use to add new row in invoiceTable with new value of dialog box input : invoiceBean

```
public void addRow() {
    invoiceProductsServicesDetail = new InvoiceProductsServicesDetail();
    invoiceDao = new InvoiceDao();
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) facesContext.getViewRoot()
            .findComponent("form:invoiceTable");

    UIComponent uiTable = ComponentUtils.findParentForm(facesContext,
            dataTable);

    final AjaxBehavior behavior = new AjaxBehavior();

    try {
        if (descriptionOfGoodsOrService != ""
                && descriptionOfGoodsOrService != null && rate != 0
                && quantity != 0) {

            invoiceProductsServicesDetail.setSerialNumber(dataTable
                    .getRowCount() + 1);
            invoiceProductsServicesDetail
                    .setDescriptionOfGoodsOrService(descriptionOfGoodsOrService);
            invoiceProductsServicesDetail.setHsnCode(hsnCode);
            invoiceProductsServicesDetail
                    .setPercentDiscount(percentDiscount);
            invoiceProductsServicesDetail.setQuantity(quantity);
            invoiceProductsServicesDetail.setRate(rate);
            invoiceProductsServicesDetail.setInvoiceId(id);

            invoiceProductsServicesDetails
                    .add(invoiceProductsServicesDetail);

            amount = (rate * quantity);
            this.grossTotal = amount = (amount - (amount * (percentDiscount / 100)));
            this.netTotal = ((amount) + (amount * (Constants.VAT / 100)) + (amount * (Constants.SERVICE_TAX / 100)));

            System.out.println(grossTotal);
            System.out.println(netTotal);

            invoiceDao
                    .insertInvoiceProductsServicesDetail(invoiceProductsServicesDetail);

            RowEditEvent rowEditEvent = new RowEditEvent(uiTable, behavior,
                    invoiceProductsServicesDetail);

            rowEditEvent.setPhaseId(PhaseId.UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES);
            dataTable.broadcast(rowEditEvent);
        } 
    } catch (AbortProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dialog submit button

```
<p:commandButton type="submit" value="Save New Invoice"
                action="#{invoiceBean.addRow}" update=":form:invoiceTable growl"
                process="@this invoiceTable" onsuccess="PF('addInvoice').hide();"
                onerror="PF('addInvoice').show();">
    <f:ajax render=":form:invoiceTable" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Only processes itself and the `invoiceTable` and not the `invoiceDialog` with all the values you enter in the dialog. Try changing it to

```
process="@form invoiceTable"
```

to process the whole dialog. Additionally, it is advisable to contain a dialog in an own form to be able to process the form without having to process all surrounding input elements not related to the dialog.

Comment: Thank You Boss, But I also want #{invoices.id} value in addRow() method. How can I get it ???

Comment: I'm afraid that your button opening the dialog has to set the invoice ID you create a new invoice for additionally in the backing bean, because you're not opening a new page where you could transport the invoice ID by query parameter.

Comment: It is possible in same page or not ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to store the invoice ID you want to use in the code processing the dialog in a place, where the code processing the dialog can access it.

Comment: Can you give me example like this ??